# Ejs not rendering the data but works fine for similar code?

Tags: node.js, json, ejs

I was learning nodejs with ejs. Here i am trying to work with ecommerce. In the product table I want to display product detail which include category, sub category, brand and so on. I was able to display brand and Category which is a reference type. But subcategory is not displaying the value associated value. where smae approch works for brand and category. what stupid mistake i have done i am unable to find.

My .ejs file

```
                             <div class="media align-items-center">
                                <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                                <img alt="Image placeholder" src="../../assets/img/theme/bootstrap.jpg" alt="Category Icon">
                                </a>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                <span class="name mb-0 text-sm"><%= products[i].category[0].category %></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </th>
                            <td class="budget">
                            <%= products[i].subCategory[0] %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">
                                <i class="bg-warning"></i>
                                <span class="status"><%= products[i].brand[0].brand %></span>
                            </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                <span class="completion mr-2"><%= products[i].title %></span>
                            </div>
```

Screen shot of ejs when i have above code:
[image: here electronics is the fetchec category and the subcategory is also being retrived. as you can see laptop is subcategory]

now when i cange my .ejs code of subcategory this way

```
                           <td class="budget">
                            <%= products[i].subCategory[0].subCategory %>
                            </td>
```

i get the error message saying :

```
    46|                             </th>
    47|                             <td class="budget">
 >> 48|                             <% console.log( products[i].subCategory[0].s
ubCategory) %>
    49|                             </td>
    50|                             <td>
    51|                             <span class="badge badge-dot mr-4">

Cannot read property 'subCategory' of undefined
```

Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, I see that category is an **Array** of reference id, while subCategory is a **String**. So the proper way to display the subCategory is

```
<%= products[i].subCategory %>
```

Comment: Thank you! i found out the problem and it was with the mongoDB. During the time of testong some empty data were stored so it was giving the error.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem and it was with the mongoDB. During the time of testing, some empty data were stored in database so it was giving the error. Once i deleted database and reuploaded data it was working fine.